# How can I make a link load a random php ID on the page?

Tags: php, mysql, html, refresh

Database row IDs are tied to the URLs like this:

The page for **row 2** becomes 
**site.com/index.php?id=2**

If I manually refresh index.php it displays a random record, but naturally it doesn't display the record ID in the address bar.

Is there a way to make a link display a random record while showing the id change in the address bar?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just showing the random record, choose the record's id and do a redirect to the version that shows the id.

```
$randomId = // whatever method you use to choose it
header( "Location: http://site.com/index.php?id=$randomId" );
```

Comment: Kiitoksia, Juhana. This works well (because a random ID is eventually shown in the URL bar), but it's causing a redirect loop (310) when I run it and the page doesn't load. Do you know how to correct this? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you're doing the redirect only when the id isn't specified (`!isset( $_GET[ 'id' ] )`).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
$randomId = rand(0,100); // if let's say your post IDs go from 0 to 100
header( "Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/post.php?id=$randomId" );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

You could like Juhana said, using [the header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). This wil redirect you to another page by pagereloading.

You could use HTML5 to change the addressbar without pagereloading by using the [window.history](http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page) and [jQuery for AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

The safest option is the PHP header function. Keep in mind to NOT print/echo anything before you header. In case you still get "headers already sent" use [ob_clean()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php)