# Random URL redirect using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

I have a question about adding a link to my website that when 'clicked' will send the user to a random URL stored in my **MySQL database**.

My database is titled "movie" and I would like to be able to have the user click on a link and it would send them to one of the movie page URLs stored in my database.

EX: The user clicks the "Random" link and gets taken to a movie page from my database(I have about 110 URLs listed with a unique Id).

Would I use something like:

- header('Location: 'xxxxx);

To accomplish this?

I know I should be able to accomplish this task using PHP, I am just having trouble figuring this one out. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to implement anything yet?  If so, what have you tried and where are you running into problems?

Comment: yes, the header() call is one way you can redirect.

Comment: $query = ("SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10");

Comment: I am using this query to randomly add movies to the homepage but I don't know how to redirect them to another page

Comment: Is there a way to use this in the header() somehow and just have it randomly select from the database?

Comment: You can accomplish that with a mix of php and javascript ;)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think that I might have found a simple solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006205/how-can-i-make-a-link-load-a-random-php-id-on-the-page

Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the query you posted selects one random movie, and that the field where the url is stored is called 'url'.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM movie ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10")
                  or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($result);
header('Location: '.$row['url']);
```

This should redirect to the url in the database.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mt_rand("", ""); // this creates random numbers and use it in a variable as:
$id= mt_rand("1", "110");
// hatever id number is generated it will put out that one in the query but it is only for one if you want multiple put $id in a for loop  than print the result in while loop.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM movie WHERE id= '$id' LIMIT 0, 10")
                  or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($result);
header('Location: '.$row['url']);
```

Comment: I apologize but I am still very new to PHP and am wondering how I might implement this into my HTML code.  So, I am able to use this to generate a random URL, but how might I implement it into my HTML code so that when a user clicks an <a href xxxx> they will be taken to this random page?

Comment: Perhaps I am unfamiliar with the correct terminology to get my question across? Your answer looks like it should work though...

Comment: well, first you should clerify this, you want one singli link that leads to this page where the page displays random movies from the database? and the other thing is, "Or  do you want to display some random movies from the database and user will choose one single movie from the output?" then i can be more specific.

Comment: The first is correct.  I would like one single link that leads to a page where the page displays one random movie from the database.